# Definite integration that results in inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, self-learning

I try to evaluate this integrat

$$\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$

It seems simple.

$$\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\arctan(\sqrt{3})-\arctan(1)$$

My question is what exact number it is?

Should it be $\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{12}$?

Or should it be $(k_1\pi+\frac{\pi}{3})-(k_2\pi+\frac{\pi}{4})=(k_1-k_2)\pi+\frac{\pi}{12}$?

$k_1,k_2=0,\pm 1,\pm2,... $

I think the definite integral should be **A** number, but there seems can be many numbers for the results.

I think I may miss some very basic concption here.

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: $\arctan x$ takes values only on $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Comment: $\arctan x$ for real arguments $x$ refers to values taken on the principal branch.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I did not see this before.

Comment: Bames may add that whatever pi length you choose to define arctan on.. result is always same. While what op did is not correct. If you define arctan to take values from 90 to 270, answer will be same.

Comment: @king then you will have a different answer

Comment: No not at all. Brabches of arctan differ by a constant pi. So finding definite integral makes no difference

Comment: I still don't get it. Suppose x= arctan(1), then x can be $\frac{\pi}{4}$, it also can be $\frac{5\pi}{4}$, and so one then which one I choose?  I agree with bames.

Comment: @KingTut : One of the nonprincipal values of the $\arctan\sqrt 3$ is $\frac{4\pi}3,$ and $\frac{4\pi} 3 - \frac \pi 4$ is quite incorrect as a value of the integral. $\qquad$

Comment: @michael doesn't make sense. I am saying if we define  arctan on 90 to 270. How you get 45 there

Comment: @KingTut : Maybe you should write clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\arctan\sqrt3 - \arctan 1 = \frac \pi 3 - \frac \pi 4 = \frac{4\pi}{12} - \frac{3\pi}{12} = \frac{(4-3)\pi}{12} = \frac \pi {12}.
$$
One of a number of ways to see that this need not involve any of the "nonprincipal" values of the arctangent is this:
$$
\text{If } 1 \le x \le \sqrt 3 \text{ then } \frac 1 2 \ge \frac 1 {1+x^2} \ge \frac 1 4,
$$
$$
\text{so } \frac{\sqrt 3-1}2 \ge \int_1^{\sqrt 3} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} \ge \frac {\sqrt3-1} 4.
$$

Comment: No I didnt and this answer is wrong.

Comment: @KingTut : What the phrase "No I didn't" refers to is unclear, since this answer says nothing about what you did, nor does it mention you, and a statement that the answer is wrong could be helpful, but only if it's specific.

Comment: Your answer was wrong and you are trying to cover it up by changing 'cannot' to 'need not'. My question is that arctan can be defined over any fixed range of length pi. Say 90 degree to 270 degrees. It's just adding a constant to antiderivative of $1/(1+x^2)$.  Hope you understand what I say.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\tan(x)$ is many one as its periodic with period $\pi$. As a result for defining an inverse we need to fix our range to a fixed length $\pi$.

We can define $\arctan_1(x) : \Bbb R \to (k\pi-\tfrac{\pi}{2}, k\pi + \tfrac{\pi}{2}), k \in \Bbb Z$. We get our standard $\arctan(x)$ function by putting $k=0$.

Now we see that the integral

$$\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\sqrt{3}} \dfrac{1}{1+x^2} dx &=\arctan_1(x) |_{1}^{\sqrt{3}}\\
 &= k\pi + \tfrac{\pi}{3} -(k\pi + \tfrac{\pi}{4}) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{12}
\end{align}$$

is independant of branch of definition. This is self evident since $\arctan_1(x) = \arctan(x) + k\pi$.

Comment: Upvote, but I think it is not necessary they have the same k

Comment: I was just showing that the antiderivatives only differ by constant so no difference on definite integral (sic.) as in my comment.

Comment: @DeepNorth Answer perpetuated by Michael is plain wrong.

Comment: But it seems correct to me, such as $\frac 1 2 \ge \frac 1 {1+x^2} \ge \frac 1 4$, then we just integrate from $1$ to $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @DeepNorth Havent you been taught this? $\int f(x) dx = F(x) + K$ so we can in fact use any branch we wish of arctan?

Comment: yes, but I think the definite integral is only **A** number, it cannot be many numbers. I mean  $arctan (\sqrt{3})$ can be $\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ and $arctan(1)$ can be $\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ then $arctan(\sqrt{3})-arctan(1)$ is not a definite number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74040/discussion-between-king-tut-and-deep-north).